# Installing sklearn on AWS deeplearning AMI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn

I'm trying to install sklearn onm an AWS DeepLearning AMI, with Conda and an assortment of backends pre-installed. I'm following ScikitLearn's website instructions:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn 
$ source activate python3
$ jupyter notebook
```

In Jupyter notebook:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Scaling the data
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-884b8a303194> in <module>()
     12 
     13 #Scaling the data
---> 14 from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
     15 sc = MinMaxScaler()                           #scaling using normalisation
     16 training_set1 = sc.fit_transform(training_set1)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Comment: Have you tried switching the order of the first two commands? You've likely installed scikit-learn into your base-anaconda environment, but not into your python3 environment.

Comment: Oh! Interesting seems like sci-kit is now working on python environment, but not the tensorflow36 environment, do I have to install new packages in each conda environment?

Comment: yes you do :) if you would like a detailed explanation on why, let me know and ill write something up for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the virtual environment **first** "source activate python3", then install scikit-learn.  Without activating the virtual environment, you are installing into the base python and not into the virtual environment.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Did you install "scikit-learn", 
try: `conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn` 
or : first create virtual env and try: `conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn` 
to create virutal env: `conda create -n *yourenvname* python=*x.x* anaconda`

Answer (score 0):

And in case anybody didn't know how to install packages in each conda environment, it is (as in this case my environment of choice was `Tensorflow` in *Python 3.6*) here is the command I used my *mac bash*, and in my EC2 environment:

```
ubuntu@ip ***.***.**.***:~$ source activate tensorflow_p36
```

and then:

```
ubuntu@ip ***.***.**.***:~$ conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
```